# dimension of graph

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I have a really rudimentary question hope to clear out:

If $f: V \rightarrow V$, where $f$ is a linear map and $V$ is a vector space. Then what is the dimension of $\operatorname{graph}(f)$? To my understanding, $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ is $V \times V$, but with $\dim V$. Is this correct?

Comment: This depends on your definition of dimension. Is it Hausdorff dimension? Topological dimension? Dimension of manifolds? Regardless, $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ is the subset of $V\times V$ given by $\{(v,f(v)) : v\in V\}$. It is homeomorphic to $V$ via projection onto the first coordinate.

Comment: Clear and accurate, thanks @user15464! I guess I am talking about Dimension of manifolds, but it is Topological dimension, right?

Comment: For dimensions of manifolds, the dimension of the graph is the same as the dimension of $V$, since $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ and $V$ are diffeomorphic. By topological dimension, I meant the following generalization of the dimension of a manifold: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension

Comment: @user15464 I believe continuity is needed to claim that the graph is homeomorphic to the domain. [X and a graph of a continuous function are homeomorphic](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2003;task=show_msg;msg=0178.0001) at Ask A Topologist or [Graph of a function homeomorphic to a space implies continuity of the map?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49559/).\\ MathSnail: I think that this question needs some clarifying. What are your assumptions about $f$ and $V$? (I thought that you are talking about linear maps and vector spaces until I saw tags and comments.)

Comment: Hi @MartinSleziak, yeah, I was talking about linear maps and vector spaces. And later people generalized my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said this question suppose to be a basic one, so user15464 answered it. Though other comments provide valuable resource and insight.

graph($f$) is the subset of $V \times V$ given by {$(v,f(v)):v\in V$}. It is homeomorphic to $V$ via projection onto the first coordinate.

For dimensions of manifolds, the dimension of the graph is the same as the dimension of $V$, since graph($f$) and $V$ are diffeomorphic.